# HTTP response problem in blackberry real device

Tags: blackberry

i am doing a simple http request to the server and server is returning 0
problem is that

on simulator i am getting "0" (expected)

and on real device i am getting "text/html ||||| |||||, <|||||0" (unwanted response)

am i missing something?

Comment: It might help to post some of the code you're using to establish the connection and read data from it.

Answer (score 0):

That depends. Are you accessing the HTTP server via BES or BIS? If so then you need to be aware that the device does not actually establish an HTTP connection to the server, the BES or BIS does that on behalf of the device. It does some other helpful things that may not be expected.

Comment: No i am not accessing http server via BES or BIS.

Comment: Hmm, so you have appended ;deviceSide=true to your connection URL? Posting some code might help.

Comment: i am just using http connection code given in api doc. but the only difference is user agent when i am using  c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
i am getting null
and when i am not using any user agent i am getting 
text/html ||||| |||||, <|||||0. 
@richard i am using right connection.

Comment: can you show what HTTP headers are being sent back by the server?